# How to make a md-radio-button selected by default within md-radio-groups

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have some 3 radio buttons in buttton group which is used for filtering the data now i want to get a button selected by default when page loads

Here is the code

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="status" aria-label="filter" ng-model="status" name="patient" layout="row">
     <md-radio-button value="">All</md-radio-button>
     <md-radio-button value="active"> Active </md-radio-button>
     <md-radio-button value="inactive">inActive</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove multiple `ng-model` from `md-radio-group` , it should be there only one time.

**Component Side**

```
status = 'active';
```

**Template side :**

```
<md-radio-group [ngModel]="status">
```

---

OR

**Like this :**

```
<md-radio-button value="active" [checked]='true'> Active </md-radio-button>
```

Comment: @RahulUnnikrishnan, try the first one that's the good way to go